# Route issue:Class Controller does not exist in Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, controller, routes

I am creating a profile section. 
And `show.blade.php` is the profile edit part.

But I cannot see `show.blade.php.`

I got a following error.

[image: error image]

Here is my code.

> web.php

```
Route::resource('channels', 'ChannelController');
```

php artisan route:list in terminal. And this is the result.
[image: php artisan route:list]

**app.blade.php**   once I click here I can jump to show.blade.php

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('channels.show', auth()->user()->channel->id) }}"> My Channel</a>
```

**controller.php**

```
<?php

namespace Laratube\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;
}
```

**ChannelController.php**

```
    <?php

namespace Laratube\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ChannelController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Channel $channel)
    {
        return view('channels.show', compact('channel'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

> show.blade.php

@extends('layouts.app')

```
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    {{ $channel->name }}
                </div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form id="update-channel-form" action="{{ route('channels.update', $channel->id) }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        @csrf

                        @method('PATCh')
                        <div class="form-group">   
                            <label for="name" class="form-control-label">
                                Name
                            </label>
                            <input id="name" name="name" value="{{ $channel->name }}" type="text" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="description" class="form-control-label">
                                Description
                            </label>
                            <textarea name="description" id="description" cols="3" rows="3" class="form-control">
                                {{ $channel->description }}
                            </textarea>
                        </div>

                        <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit">Update</button>

                    </form>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

I tried following things.

```
    php artisan cache:clear

    composer update

    composer dump-autoload

    php artisan db:seed
```

But still it doesn't work.

I am glad if someone helps me out.

I guess, I have something wrong with my route. This route also did not work.

```
Route::resource('channels', 'ChannelController')->name('channels.show');
```

Comment: add your controller code also.

Comment: Sorry, I added. Please check this out.

Comment: you should include model class file in your controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess (without your controller code) is that you didn't import the model `Channel`. The message is quite clear, it tries to retrieve the model class from it's current directory: `Laratube\Http\Controllers\`.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't import the Channel Model in your controller. 
Add the line in the top **use** section of your controller.

```
use Laratube\Channel;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    //In Your Controller
    <?php

    namespace Laratube\Http\Controllers;

    use Laratube\Channel;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    class ChannelController extends Controller
    {


//in show function
public function show()
    {
        $channel = Channel::get();
        return view('channels.show', compact('channel'));
    }
```